# Why does WriteProcessMemory need the handle value passed in, not the ID of the target process?

Tags: windows, system, kernel-density, windows-kernel

In the Windows system, we can modify the memory of another process across processes. For example, if process A wants to modify the memory of process B, A can call the system function [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory). The approximate form is as follows:

```cpp
BOOL flag = WriteProcessMemory(handler, p_B_addr, &p_A_buff, write_size); ...
```

This function return a Boolean value, which represents whether the write operation is successful. It needs to pass four parameters, let's take a look at these four parameters:

1. handler. This is a process handle, and it can be used to find B process.
2. p_B_addr. In process B, the address offset to be written into memory.
3. p_A_buff. In process A, the pointer to the write data buffer.
4. write_size. The number of bytes to write.

I am confused about the first parameter handler, which is a variable of type HANDLE. For example, when our program is actually running, the ID of process B is 2680, and then I want to write memory to process B. First I need to use this 2680 to get the handle of process B in process A. The specific form is handler=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 2680), and then you can use this handler to fall into the kernel to modify the memory of process B.

Since they are all trapped in kernel functions to modify memory across processes, why is the WriteProcessMemory function not designed to be in the form of WriteProcessMemory(B_procID, p_B_addr, &p_A_buff, write_size)?

Among them, B_procID is the ID of the B process, since each process they all have unique IDs. Can the system kernel not find the physical address that the virtual address of the B process can map through this B_procID? Why must the process handle index of the B process in the A process be passed in?

Comment: The kernel implements various objects and these are exposed to usemode via handles. Why would this particular function differ from that paradigm?

Comment: I personally think it's because of convenience. Recently, I was writing a program that reads and writes memory across processes. At first, I used my intuitive method: WriteProcessMemory(pID..., then the program always failed, and I also found the failure. The reason is that the way I use it is wrong: a handle should be passed, not a pID.

Comment: As you can see, after I write the code in the correct way, I have to go through an OpenProcess process to get the handle of the target process, so I thought, why can't I use the process ID directly? Through the process ID, The kernel should also be able to access the memory of the target process?

Comment: Going back ten thousand steps, even if not, the system designers can completely encapsulate the WriteProcessMemory function, at least for the user, it is very convenient to use, user-level You don't have to do so much.

Comment: A handle allows additional security to attach to the handle object. If you open a process without write rights your modify method will get an access denied back. That way you can implement policies that the users of your exposed handles can do only the intended things. If you would go directly via the process id such a design would not be possible. Another thing is that with a pid based API you are open to race conditions. If the process dies and then a totally different process gets the same process id (they are recycled) very bad things will happen.

Comment: True for all kernel objects, opening a handle ensures that the kernel object stays valid.  Even if the object stops being useful, like the process terminating.  The process ID isn't good enough, doesn't extend object life and the ID gets re-used.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance of the two great gods upstairs! Regarding the lifespan of the process, it is indeed a factor that I did not consider. I understand, thank you tow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons, all touched on in the comments.

1. Lifetime. The process id is simply a number, knowing the id does not keep the process alive. Having a open handle to a process means the kernel EPROCESS structure and the process address space will stay intact, even if said process finishes by calling `ExitProcess`. Windows tries to not re-use the id for a new process right away but it will happen some time in the future given enough time.
2. Security/Access control. In Windows NT, access control is performed when you open a object, not each time you interact with the object. In this case, the kernel needs to know that the caller has PROCESS_VM_WRITE and PROCESS_VM_OPERATION access to the process. This is related to point 3, efficiency.
3. Speed. Windows could of course implement a `WriteProcessMemoryById` function that calls `OpenProcess`+`WriteProcessMemory`+`CloseHandle` but this encourages sub optimal design as well as opening you up to race conditions related to point 1. The same applies to "why is there no `WriteFileByFilename` function" (and all other Read/Write functions).